# What's wrong with this Makefile and LaTeX?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to use the following Makefile in order to compile a LaTeX project.

```
# LaTeX Makefile
FILE=Tesis
all: $(FILE).pdf
.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm *.aux *.blg *.out *.bbl *.log *.dvi *.idx *.lof *.toc *.pdf
$(FILE).pdf: $(FILE).tex
$(FILE).tex: Generalidades.tex Analisis.tex Diseno.tex Construccion.tex Conclusiones.tex Tesis.bib
        latex $(FILE).tex
        bibtex $(FILE)
        latex $(FILE)
        dvipdfm $(FILE).dvi
```

The file Tesis.pdf doesn't exist. However after running make I get:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'
```

What is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency

```
$(FILE).pdf: $(FILE).tex
```

has no rule associated with it – it's missing a sequence of indented lines which tell `make` how to make the PDF from the `.tex` file. That means it'll *always* be up to date.

Your second dependency, on the other hand:

```
$(FILE).tex: Generalidades.tex Analisis.tex ...
    latex $(FILE).tex
```

says ‘$(FILE).tex depends on Generalidades.tex Analisis.tex ..., and to make it [ie, the .tex file] up to date, run latex’.  That's not what you mean.

Try

```
$(FILE).pdf: $(FILE).tex Generalidades.tex Analisis.tex ...
    latex $(FILE).tex
    ...
```

(By the way, if you use `pdflatex` then you can generate a PDF file directly from the `.tex` source.  You'll have to use `.pdf` figures rather than `.eps` ones, but it's easy to convert `.eps` figures to `.pdf`).